# For Sister Grimm's Super Power, where does the plot twist go if you can't play it?

Tags: vs-2pcg

The Sister Grimm supporting character's Super Power reads:

> **{C} Any Combat {Y}:** Search your deck for an **{C} Combat** plot twist with a different name from each plot twist in your KO pile and play it if able.

What happens if you can't play it? I assume that if I search for a card and can't play it, it stays in my deck. Part of the problem here is that I'm used to MtG, where the card would explicitly tell you what to do in the alternative case.

Answer (score -1):

It does tell you, it says play it if able. You are not able so you can't use it, it stays in your K.O pile not your deck.

Comment: This doesn't really jive with the wording. It can't "stay" in your KO pile because it was never there; the card you're searching for is in your deck.